# use ImageIO.write Java to save jpg in real time

Tags: java, file

There is my code. I try to analysis data and create the graph and save to local driver. The program is working fine now. But I find out that the jpg file only can be save to local drive after the program is all finished. However, there are too many data and too many graph need to be created. The whole program may run for hours. I am just wondering could I make it save the jpg in real time? so I can view all graph it just created. Or I don't have to give up all graph if I need to stop the program before it finish all.

Thank you

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("go");
    super.paintComponent(g);
    BufferedImage jpg = new BufferedImage(1040, 400,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = jpg.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    double total=0;
    // Draw ordinate.
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(SPACE, SPACE, SPACE, h-SPACE));
    // Draw abcissa.
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(SPACE, h/2, w-SPACE, h/2));
    double xInc = (double)(w - 2*SPACE)/(data.size()-1);
    double scale = (double)(h/2 - SPACE*3)/getMax();
    // Mark data points.
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        double x = SPACE + i*xInc;
        double y;
        if(data.get(i)!=0){
            y= h/2 - SPACE - scale*data.get(i);
            total = total + data.get(i);
        }else{
            y = h/2;
        }

        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y-1, 4, 4));

    }
    try {
        ImageIO.write(jpg, "JPEG", new File("111\\"+total/data.size() + ".jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What I mean is, is there any function I can use like file.close() that allowed me to create file when it done instead of store in memory and waiting for the program finish. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`paintComponent` is called as event handling, whenever repainting is needed. And may occur often. Painting should be done fast too. So save the image outside the paint component.

Maybe check the file existence, or number the files.

Call `Graphics.dispose()` too, to prevent resource leaks.

```
BufferedImage jpg = new BufferedImage(1040, 400,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2 = jpg.createGraphics();
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
paintComponent(g2);
g2.dispose();
```

---

Also you picked a program-relative folder. Below I picked the user's folder, and
possibly create a directory `111` if not present (`mkdirs`).

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
File imgFile = new File(userHome + "/111/" + (total/data.size()) + ".jpg");
// Windows still allows `/` instead of `\` as path separator.
imgFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
System.out.println("Writing to image: " + imgFile.getPath());
...
    ImageIO.write(jpg, "JPEG", imgFile);
```

Comment: I am just wondering why I cannot see them in my folder if the program is still process next data

Comment: Extended my answer with folder handling.